# Objects within functions not found

Tags: r, function, object

I recently updated to R 3.4.0 and I am running Linux Mint 17.1. When I first updated R everything worked fine (I think). Now many basic functions from different packages fail. In every case it appear that the function calls another function internally but then can not find the temporary object that was created. Here is an example:

```
   > library(nlme)
   > fm1 <- gnls(weight ~ SSlogis(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), Soybean, weights = varPower())
   Error: object 'fit_gnls' not found
```

The exact same error occurs for many functions from many packages and I am stuck. Any suggestions would be welcomed. I did try a complete reinstall of R, with no effect.

Comment: I can not reproduce this error with `R 3.4.0` on `x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)` and `nlme_3.1-131`. Perhaps share your `sessionInfo()` after the error to see what package versions you are using. Maybe also look at `conflicts()` to see if you are masking any functions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there were updated versions of many packages available but the "update packages" button in Rstudio was telling me that they were all up to date. I ran update.packages() and all is working again.